# Which is the correct definition for the word "appeal" in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Pathos appeals to the emotions of the audience and elicits feelings that already reside in them. (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathos)

TFD definitions for "appeal"
2. To have recourse, as for corroboration; resort: I appeal to your sense of justice.
4. To be attractive or interesting: The idea didn't appeal to me.

Does this sentence mean "Pathos is attractive to the emotions of the audience.." or "Pathos has a recourse to the emotions of the audience..."?

Comment: attracting, not attractive.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would come under sense B2 from[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/appeal)

> the quality in someone or something that makes him, her, or it attractive or interesting

or sense 1 from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appeal)

> : to arouse a sympathetic response

But the specific form "appeal to" as used here has a slightly different sense, in my experience as a native speaker.

To say that "X appeals to Y" when Y is an emotion or an aspect of a person (or of a group of people) means that is is the Y aspect that is stimulated or addressed by X. This is a specific form of the "attracted" sense, in my view,. but it might deserve its own sense in a dictionary.

> Pathos appeals to the emotions of the audience

means that pathos is responded to in an emotional way, not a logical or analytic way. It reaches out to the emotions of the audience, if it is in those emotions that it finds a response, if it does find one.

Some (invented) examples:

> - Many works of science fiction appeal to a reader's sense of adventure. (The sense of adventrue is stimulated and is what m,akes the reader like the story, if s/he does.)
> - Classic detective stories appeal to the sense of justice s well as to the pleasure of solving a puzzle.
> - A hard-luck story appeals to our sense of pity. (Pity is what makes a person respond to  a hard-luck story)
> - Much comedy appeals to our sense of the incongruous. (It is the incongruous or out-of-place elements that make many things funny.)
> - The conspiracy theory appealed to his latent anger. (His existing anger made the theory attractive to him.)